# How can i concat a string using lambda expression

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a method that require to add items from a collection in comma separated form.
For each dressing items i want it's dressing info concatenated in comma separated form and return it as a string. But the way i am doing it fails and say the parameter not correct.

I am trying it like this

```
private string GetAllFreeItemNames(CategoryType catType)
{
    if (this.DressingItems != null)
    {
        //var ls = FreeDressingItems;//.FindAll(I => I. == this.TypeName);
        return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(I => I.DressingInfo).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Could some body please help me with this.

Comment: Huh? Dunno what you want to do.

Comment: For each dressing items i want it's dressing info concated in comma separated orm and return it as a string.

Comment: What happens when you run above code?

Comment: And what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: From C# 4.0 onward you don't need the `ToArray()`: `string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(I => I.DressingInfo))`

Comment: it says String.Join has some invalid arguments

Comment: What is the type of `I.DressingInfo`? It must be a string. If it is, you don't need the `ToArray()` because there's an overload of [`string.Join()` which takes an `IEnumerable<string>` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx). IF it isn't a string, you need to use `.ToString()` or some other mechanism to convert it to a string.

Comment: This question does not have neither enough information to guess what question is, not well formatted question. Also there are too many undefined variables (for us) in your code.

Comment: DresingINfo is an object of a class and i missed to put another dot to extract catName. it does work thanks Matthew Watson.

Answer (score 3):

`DressingInfo` must be a `string`

If it's a class, perhaps it has some properties that describes it (for example, `Name`)

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.Name).ToArray());
```

or something more complex

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.Name + " " + p.DressingInfo.Colour).ToArray());
```

or perhaps it has an overload of `ToString()`

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Note that from C# 4.0 you don't need the `ToArray()`, so

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.Name));
```

or

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.Name + " " + p.DressingInfo.Colour));
```

or

```
return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(p => p.DressingInfo.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 private string GetAllFreeItemNames(CategoryType catType)
{
  if (this.DressingItems != null)
  {
    //var ls = FreeDressingItems;//.FindAll(I => I. == this.TypeName);
    return string.Join(",", this.DressingItems.Select(I => I.DressingInfo.ToString()).ToArray());
  }
}
```

As suggested by `p.s.w.g`, you can omit the `ToArray()` since .NET 4.0.

NOTE: You have to override `ToString()` method of the type `DressingInfo` has to get the expected result.

Comment: You don't have to call `.ToArray()` in .NET 4.0 or later because there's [this convenient overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx). In fact you won't even have to call `.ToString()`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thanks! added it as a notice.